# TypeError: Type contract testAdoption is not implicitly convertible to expected type address

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/Adoption.sol";

contract testAdoption{
    Adoption adoption = Adoption(DeployedAddresses.Adoption());

    //Testing the adopt() function
    function testUserCanAdoptPet() public{
        uint returnedId = adoption.adopt(8);

        uint expected = 8;

        Assert.equal(returnedId, expected, "Adoption of pet ID 8 should be recorded");
    }

    //Testing retrieval of a single pet's owner
    function testGetAdopterAddressBypetId() public {
        //Expected owner is this contract
        address expected = this;

        address adopter = adoption.adopters(8);

        Assert.equal(adopter, expected, "Owner of pet ID 8 should be recorded");
    }

    //Testing retrieval of all pet owners
    function testGetAdopterAddressBypetIdInArray() public {
        //Expected owner is this contract
        address expected = this;

        //Store adopters in memory rather than contract's storage
        address[16] memory adopters = adoption.getAdopters();

        Assert.equal(adopters[8], expected, "Owner of pet ID 8 should be recorded");
    }


}
```

> TypeError: Type contract testAdoption is not implicitly convertible to
>   expected type address.
>           address expected = this;
>           ^---------------------^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `expected` is of type `address`, while `this` is of type `contract testAdoption`. You can cast a contract to an address to make it work.

```
address expected = address(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Implicit address conversion for `this` was deprecated in solidity 0.5.0ish.

You need to do `address(this)` now.

Answer (score 0):

Works indeed, new code is then:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/Adoption.sol";

contract TestAdoption
{
  Adoption adoption = Adoption(DeployedAddresses.Adoption());

  // The id of the pet that will be used for testing
  uint expectedPetId = 8;

  //The expected owner of adopted pet is this contract
  address expectedAdopter = address(this);

  // Testing the adopt() function
  function testUserCanAdoptPet() public
  {
    uint returnedId = adoption.adopt(8);

    uint expected = 8;

    Assert.equal(returnedId, expected, "Adoption of pet ID 8 should be recorded.");
  }

  // Testing retrieval of a single pet's owner
  function testGetAdopterAddressByPetId() public
  {
    // Expected owner is this contract
    address expected = address(this);

    address adopter = adoption.adopters(8);

    Assert.equal(adopter, expected, "Owner of pet ID 8 should be recorded.");
  }

  // Testing retrieval of all pet owners
  function testGetAdopterAddressByPetIdInArray() public
  {
    // Expected owner is this contract
    address expected = address(this);

    // Store adopters in memory rather than contract's storage
    address[16] memory adopters = adoption.getAdopters();

    Assert.equal(adopters[8], expected, "Owner of pet ID 8 should be recorded.");
  }

}
```